# Android Marketplace, how would I email a link that would open the Market place from a device?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to offer a webform on my app's website that sends an email to  the provided address, that if opened from a Android device would launch the marketplace on the phone.  I have used the following:

http://market.android.com/details?id=package.apk

It takes me to a loading screen, but I get Sorry, the application Market (process.com.android.vending) has stopped unexpectedly.  Please try again.

Is this possible?  It seems that it would be due to the marketplace even trying to load???

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the `market` protocol.

```
market://search?q=pname:com.yourapp.packagename
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the package name wrong.  I got it to work